# HTTP 500 - Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat7, jndi

I have been searching to fix that problem for 3 days reading forums... Then I decided to ask for some help.  Nedless to say that your help would be highly appreciated :-)

I created a jndi resource for the mysql connexion in Tomcat context.xml instance in Eclipse
My web app works fine when I start the server from eclipse.  It doesn't work fine when I start the web app from eclipse 'Run configurations' with that goals : clean tomcat7:run.  My aim is to delegate the build, deploy, start server to maven from eclipse.

I've put the mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar in Tomcat_Home/lib.

I don't want to put the datasource configuration in the app (no META-INF....) as one goal of jndi is to place the datasource info out of the app.

Thank you for reading and for the time you'll spend to find a solution.

Technical specifications

- eclipse : juno release2
- spring tool suite : 3.4
- wtp
- m2e : 1.4
- maven : 3.0.2
- jdk : 1.6.21
- tomcat : 7.0.25

  mysql : 5.6.14

stacktrace

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:927)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


root cause 

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:702)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:178)
    com.marc.springmvc3.dao.PersonDAO.getPersonById(PersonDAO.java:26)
    com.marc.springmvc3.service.PersonService.getAllPersons(PersonService.java:18)
    com.marc.springmvc3.mvc.PersonController.getListOfPerson(PersonController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:123)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:723)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


root cause 

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:702)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:178)
    com.marc.springmvc3.dao.PersonDAO.getPersonById(PersonDAO.java:26)
    com.marc.springmvc3.service.PersonService.getAllPersons(PersonService.java:18)
    com.marc.springmvc3.mvc.PersonController.getListOfPerson(PersonController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:123)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:723)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:702)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:178)
    com.marc.springmvc3.dao.PersonDAO.getPersonById(PersonDAO.java:26)
    com.marc.springmvc3.service.PersonService.getAllPersons(PersonService.java:18)
    com.marc.springmvc3.mvc.PersonController.getListOfPerson(PersonController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:123)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:723)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.marc</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-mvc-3</artifactId>
<name>spring-mvc-3</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  MYSQL driver-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-3</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                <port>8080</port>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                <username>ssss</username>
                <password>dddddddddd</password>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.27</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>                
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Servers/tomcat-config/tomcat-users.xml (in Eclipse)

```
    <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="ssss" password="dddddddddd" roles="admin"/>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- database jndi reference -->
    <description>MySQL Test App</description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
        jndi-name="jdbc/TestDB"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        resource-ref="true"/>   

    <bean id="personDao" class="com.marc.springmvc3.dao.PersonDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>
```

tomcat context.xml (in eclipse)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

 <Resource  name="jdbc/TestDB" 
            username="xxx" 
            password="xxxxxxxx" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytest"
            auth="Container" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100" 
            maxIdle="30" 
            maxWait="10000"
            initialSize="1"/>


<!--      <ResourceLink name="jdbc/TestDB"
        global="jdbc/TestDB"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"/> -->
</Context>
```

Comment: You haven't defined what `jdbc/TestDB` is anywhere, therefore you have no database driver

Comment: Yes, `context.xml` is wrong and should contains definition of `jdbc/TestDB`. Proper `config.xml` added in answer.

Comment: I made a mistake in my post.  I've just updated with the web.xml and the tomcat context.xml (eclipse)

Comment: Also consider upvoting my answer, because I put some work to answer to your wrong question :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer.  There is a message saying that I need 15 reputations to vote and I've just registered :-(  I'm sorry.  Anyway thank you for your help.  I updated the tomcat_home/conf/context.xml.  It's still not working but I think that the solution is to run maven goals from command line...

Comment: Oh, I see, so then I upovoted you :)

Comment: I've got the privilege to upvote now...  So I did :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've eventually found out the solution and I'll share it with those who are encountering the same problem.

Create the META-INF folder under src/main/webapp as WEB-INF sibling
Move the Tomcat-config/context.xml file to the META-INF folder.  You'll see in the pom.xml that this file is not going to be part of the WAR file.

META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

 <Resource  name="jdbc/TestDB" 
            username="xxxx" 
            password="xxxxxxxxxx" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB"
            auth="Container" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100" 
            maxIdle="30" 
            maxWait="10000"
            initialSize="1"/>
</Context>
```

Adapt the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server> <!-- user + password defined in the Maven/conf/settings.xml-->
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                <port>8080</port>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                <contextFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml</contextFile> <!--The path of the Tomcat context XML file. This is not used for war deployment mode.-->
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> <!-- driver mysql -->
                    <version>5.1.27</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml
The id is referenced in the pom.xml.  The username and the password are declared in the tomcat-users.xml

```
<server>
    <id>TomcatServer</id>
    <username>xxxxx</username>
    <password>xxxxxxxxx</password>
</server>
```

Eclipse / Run - Run configurations ...

- create new launch configuration
- Base direrctory ${workspace_loc:/your project name}
- Goals clean tomcat7:run
- Apply
- Run

Next time you can click on the arrow near the Run As... button in the ToolBar and select the configuration you want to run.  The Stop and Relaunch buttons are very useful.

Comment: I think you can simplify this configuration, simply dont use JEE Resources if this is not your requirement :) Spring has very nice support for environment configuration, profiles etc.

Answer (score 5):

I think your tomcat installation is not using your `context.xml`. Please create fresh tomcat, configure `context.xml` and libs and run Tomcat directly from system (without Eclipse etc).

---

Question was updated, answer below is obsolete :/

The important part is:

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

Your driver class is `null` and connection URL is `null`.

Application configuration requires configured resource `jdbc/TestDB` on server:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and

```
  <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
    jndi-name="jdbc/TestDB"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    resource-ref="true"/>
```

But your Tomcat configuration `Servers/tomcat-config/context.xml` is wrong. It looks like spring application configuration.

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 ...
```

Standard Tomcat `context.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    username="user" password="pass" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB?characterEncoding=utf8" maxActive="8"/>

 </Context>
```

Comment: COuld you please guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548268/nested-exception-is-java-sql-sqlexception-cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Eclipse STS 3.9.3, tomcat 8.5 and Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

I spent my entire morning about this problem.
So, I did a lot of things to solve:

1. Remove jdbc dependence from my pom.

   ```
       <!-- dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency-->
   ```
2. Declaration resource TOMCAT_HOME/CONF/server.xml whit factory:

   ```
   <GlobalNamingResources>
    ...
      <Resource name="jdbc/postgres_jndi"
                 auth="Container"
                 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                 driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                 url="jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5432/db"
                 factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
                 removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
                 removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
                 timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000"
                 removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
                 logAbandoned="true"
                 username="xxx"
                 password="xxxxxx"
                 maxTotal="20"
                 maxIdle="10"
                 maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
    ...
   </GlobalNamingResources>
   ```

   I realized that I was using Eclipse STS. The tomcat resource on server.xml only works after I put the resource declaration in server.xml inside of "Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost-config" folder in my Server project. Did not work on TOMCAT_HOME/conf folder in server.xml file.
3. Change my application.yml to:

   ```
   spring:
     datasource:
       platform: postgres
       jndi-name: java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres_jndi
       type: javax.sql.DataSource
       driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
     jpa:
       hibernate:
         ddl-auto: validate
       database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
       database: POSTGRESQL
       show-sql: true
       #Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
       properties:
         hibernate:
           temp:
             use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
   ```

A application.properties will be like:

```
    spring.datasource.platform= postgres
    spring.datasource.jndi-name= java:comp/env/jdbc/postgres_jndi
    spring.datasource.type= javax.sql.DataSource
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name= org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= validate
    spring.jpa.hibernatedatabase-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    spring.jpa.database= POSTGRESQL
    spring.jpa.show-sql= true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

4. Define a context.xml file in src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml with definition:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context path="/myapp">
       <ResourceLink global="jdbc/postgres_jndi" name="jdbc/postgres_jni" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
   </Context>
   ```
5. Put the file postgresql-42.2.2.jar in the TOMCAT_HOME/lib