# nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' - Spring MVC JNDI issue

Tags: spring-mvc, jndi

I am developing SpringMvcJndiDataSourceXML example. In this example I'm facing below error. I found many links but none of them worked fine for me. Although this is duplicate question, but still I'd like to get the answer to the following question. Please guide.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
    at net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl.list(UserDAOImpl.java:24)
    at net.codejava.spring.controller.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2160)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2144)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

I'm using tomcat for deployment.
**spring-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spring" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/UsersDB"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDao" class="net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">   
    <display-name>SpringMvcJndiDataSourceXML</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- database JNDI reference -->
    <description></description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DBConnection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/test</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

tomcat **server.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
    license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
    information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
    You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
    this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
    the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. --><!-- Note: A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not define 
    subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level. Documentation at /docs/config/server.html -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
    <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html <Listener 
        className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" /> -->
    <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
    <Listener SSLEngine="on"
        className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />
    <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs -->
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />


    <Resource auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" 
        maxWait="-1" 
        name="jdbc/UsersDB" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="root" password="root"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html -->
    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by UserDatabaseRealm 
            to authenticate users -->
        <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved"
            factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase"
            pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" />
    </GlobalNamingResources>

    <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share 
        a single "Container" Note: A "Service" is not itself a "Container", so you 
        may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level. Documentation 
        at /docs/config/service.html -->
    <Service name="Catalina">

        <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more 
            named thread pools -->
        <!-- <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" maxThreads="150" 
            minSpareThreads="4"/> -->


        <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received 
            and responses are returned. Documentation at : Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html 
            (blocking & non-blocking) Java AJP Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html APR (HTTP/AJP) 
            Connector: /docs/apr.html Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 
            8080 -->
        <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            redirectPort="8443" />
        <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool -->
        <!-- <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
            connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" /> -->
        <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 This connector uses 
            the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE style configuration. When using 
            the APR/native implementation, the OpenSSL style configuration is required 
            as described in the APR/native documentation -->
        <!-- <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
            maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
            sslProtocol="TLS" /> -->

        <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


        <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes 
            every request. The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone analyzes 
            the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them on to the appropriate 
            Host (virtual host). Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

        <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie : <Engine 
            name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1"> -->
        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

            <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at: /docs/cluster-howto.html 
                (simple how to) /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
            <!-- <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/> -->

            <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords 
                via a brute-force attack -->
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI resources 
                    under the key "UserDatabase". Any edits that are performed against this UserDatabase 
                    are immediately available for use by the Realm. -->
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                    resourceName="UserDatabase" />
            </Realm>

            <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost"
                unpackWARs="true">

                <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications 
                    Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
                <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" 
                    /> -->

                <!-- Access log processes all example. Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html 
                    Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                    directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log"
                    suffix=".txt" />

                <Context docBase="SpringMvcJndiDataSourceXML" path="/SpringMvcJndiDataSourceXML"
                    reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMvcJndiDataSourceXML" />
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Server.xml** place resource under `<GlobalNamingResources>`

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
     <Resource auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" 
        maxWait="-1" 
        name="jdbc/UsersDB" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="root" password="root"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

In **Context.xml**

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/UsersDB" name="jdbc/UsersDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Comment: It worth to mention that by `context.xml` you mean the project's `META-INF/context.xml`

Comment: No in tomcat context.xml

Comment: Then could you please add some details on why there and not in the project?

Comment: Both server.xml and context.xml are files of tomcat server and hence should be work by making these changes.Suggestions mentioned here http://www.journaldev.com/2905/hibernate-tomcat-jndi-datasource-example-tutorial will guide you too.

Comment: @OlegKurbatov jndi is entirely related to web container(application server), so to make it work those two steps must be considered..then only jndi setup will be completed and one should able to access it.